# Crash on trying to set Today's Date on PickerView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uipickerview

It's concerned to PickerView, The app get crashed on this line of code -

```
[datePicker setDate:date animated:YES];
```

I am getting this error sometime-

**Assertion failure in -[_UIDatePickerView _setDate:animated:forced:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/_UIDatePickerView.m:302**

I tried to clean and run but sometimes code works perfectly but sometimes it gave same error.

Can anyone suggest any better solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly this types of error generated when you applies nil date: check values of date it is nil or/not ?? and give proper condition if you get nil value of UIDatePicker.

This is caused by the diffent locale (NSLocale) set on your device and in the simulator or your date format is wrong ,,,,, You should check if you date formatter is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is not valid date . So please try to use this one..

```
[datePicker setDate:[NSDate date] animated:YES];
```